# LWE with identity sub-matrix and reused sampled from [MP12]: why is it secure?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe

I studied this paper a while ago, but now I'm confused by the paper [*Trapdoors for Lattices:Simpler, Tighter, Faster, Smaller*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/501.pdf) by Micciancio and Peikert. Page 24 and 25, they present an algorithm that explains how to sample a pseudo random matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with a trapdoor.

### Short presentation of this section

Basically, the idea is to sample first a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ uniformly at random, sample a matrix $\mathbf{R}$ according to some distribution $\mathcal{D}$, and then compute $\mathbf{A} = [\bar{\mathbf{A}} | \mathbf{G} - \bar{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}]$ where $\mathbf{G}$ is a fixed matrix easy to invert even in the presence of noise (and I don't need the tag $\mathbf{H}$, so $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{I}$). They, if I understood correctly, they say that $\mathbf{A}$ looks random if $[\bar{\mathbf{A}} | \bar{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}]$ looks random, which makes sense, especially when we removed the tag. So from that point $\mathbf{G}$ is not useful anymore to study the indistinguishability property.

Then, they present two ways to sample $\mathbf{R}$ and choose the dimensions of $\mathbf{A}$, depending on whether you want statistical or computational indistinguishability for $\mathbf{A}$. However, the computational version looks a bit strange to me: instead of sampling $\bar{\mathbf{A}}$ uniformly at random, they seem to sample instead another matrix $\hat{\mathbf{A}} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times n}$ uniformly at random, and set $\bar{\mathbf{A}} = [\mathbf{I} | \hat{\mathbf{A}}]$. They also sample $\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_1\\\mathbf{R}_2\end{bmatrix}$ according to a discrete Gaussian. Then it means that $[\bar{\mathbf{A}} | \bar{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}] = [\mathbf{I}|\hat{\mathbf{A}}|\hat{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}_2+\mathbf{R}_1]$. And they say this matrix (up to the identity) is indistinguishable from random because it is an instance of LWE in its normal form.

### My (maybe elementary?) questions

So I have two questions:

- First, **why isn't it a problem to have a matrix identity in the final matrix** $\mathbf{A}$? I have the feeling that it leaks much more information about the secret $\mathbf{s}$, since you learn basically $\mathbf{s}^t\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{e}^t = \mathbf{s}^t+\mathbf{e}^t$ for some small error $\mathbf{e}$. In particular, you learn the most significant bits of $\mathbf{s}$ right? I don't see how you could learn this same information from $\mathbf{s}^t\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{e}^t$ when $\mathbf{A}$ is truly random. I guess you can try to do some columns operations to recover the identity, but I would expect this to increase the noise significantly.
- Secondly, **why is $[\hat{\mathbf{A}}|\hat{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}_2+\mathbf{R}_1]$ even pseudo-random?** The way I understand the normal form of LWE is that you are allowed to sample $\mathbf{s}$ directly from a small Gaussian instead of uniformly at random as explained [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/pubs/slides-barilan5.pdf) slide 10/15. So I would agree that $[\hat{\mathbf{A}}|\hat{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{R}_2+\mathbf{R}_1]$ is pseudo random if $\mathbf{R}$ was a vector. However, $\mathbf{R}$ is a matrix, so it means that each line of $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ will be used to produce several samples (one for each column or $\mathbf{R}$). So it suggests that LWE is secure also if we reuse the $\mathbf{a}$ samples several times... Am I right or did I miss something? If yes, do we know that LWE is secure when these samples are reused several times?

Thanks!

### EDIT: answer to Mark

Thanks for your answer. Thank you very much for the [PW07] reference: Lemma 6.2 is exactly what I need: it is very helpful and answers perfectly my second question! (+1)

Concerning the first question, I did try to read the relevant section of [[MR09]](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/papers/pqc.pdf) (the important part is at the very end and a bit in the beginning). However, it still looks a bit cryptic to me. I guess maybe because I'm not yet used to this link between the matrix and the lattice. And I still don't understand if I can use $\mathbf{A}$ "as it" (strange due to the "attack" I mention), or if I need some special care when using it, like sampling $s$ from a small error set (also strange not to mention it at all in the paper: later $g_{\mathbf{A}}$ is defined on all $s$), or if I can just get rid of the identity and use the rest (but then I'm not sure the correctness applies).

Concerning the reference [MR09], for example, I'm not sure how they derive page 24 the expression for $P'$. Just to make sure, when they say "Reducing the columns of E modulo the HNF", they mean some sort of LLL reduction? And after that line, the rest is quite specific to there own strange construction and I'm not sure what I can say from that. I've the feeling that this Hermitian matrix is just a convenient, efficient, representation of A in the lattice space, but that using this matrix instead of A requires some adaptation (maybe, as you say, to sample using a small $s$ instead of a uniform element, which may be the case of the [MR09] paper because they use an $a$ sampled uniformly between $-r$ and $r$... and I've the feeling that they also need to update their way of sampling $E$, by doing this reduction first). So if I need to adapt my method to use $\mathbf{A}$, then I'm surprised they don't mention it in the paper, and just define $g_\mathbf{A}$ for all $s$.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: For your first question: we would not reveal LWE samples relative to the identity submatrix $I$, only the rest of the public matrix $A$. Equivalently, we let the first part of $e$ be $-s$, to get $s^t I - s^t=0$ corresponding with the $I$ submatrix. Either view corresponds to the transformation to the “normal” form of LWE. We can do LWE inversion even in this context, as long as $(s,e)$ is short enough (exercise for the reader! Hint: multiplying the public matrix by the trapdoor matrix now yields $G+R_1$.).

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Thank you so much for the answer. So indeed, if $s$ is small the inversion works. The only problem is that in my use case it is quite important to make sure that $g(s,e) = As+e$ is defined for all $s \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$. So is there a way to make it work for all $s$? For example, does it make sense to do an "inverse Hermite optimization"? Or if I compute $As+e$ with $A$ containing the identity matrix: then I will learn some info on the significant bits of $A$, but not on the others bits (like when $s$ is small), such that $As+e$ may be indistinguishable from a random vector?

Comment: Well, $g(s,e)$ is well defined for any $s \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$; the question is whether the ordinary usage of your application really needs to use arbitrary $s$, or can be limited to use only "short" $s$. The latter is essentially without loss of generality because we can always apply the HNF transformation when using arbitrary $s$. Alternatively, you can replace the identity submatrix with a random (or random invertible) matrix (leaving the dimensions unchanged), and reveal the entire $As + e$ for arbitrary $s$. This is essentially a "reverse HNF transform."

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Thanks a lot for your answer. So the reason I was interested to have a short $s$ is that to get a good "correctness", I want to make sure that as few elements as possible as sampled from a small distribution (because this distribution doesn't have nice homomorphic properties, and therefore the correctness is often broken). But I checked and in that case both cases are indeed identical: if I don't include the identity, then I need to sample a small s, so I have n additional small terms. But if I include Id, my error e is bigger (+n).So indeed both solutions are equal,thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChrisPeikert And concerning the "reverse HNF" (sorry, I'm curious even if I don't need it), the issue I see is that I guess I cannot invert the function anymore: if I compute $(s^t [A_r, \hat{A}, G-\hat{A}R_2-R_1]+e^t)[A_r^{-1}R_1 | R_2 | I]^t= s^t G+e_1^t A_r^{-1}R_1 + e_2[R_2 | I]^t$, the noise $e_1^tA_r^{-1}R_1$ is not small anymore if $A_r$ is random, so I won't be able to invert $g$ right (and inversion is crutial for me)? Or maybe I missed something?).

Comment: You should multiply $A_r$ on the left of the *entire* parity-check matrix, effectively reversing what happens in the HNF transform (which yields an identity matrix from a random invertible one that is there at the start). Also don’t multiply $A_r^{-1}$ on the right of the parity-check matrix; that ruins everything as you’ve observed.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Oh, very true, I should have thought about that. Everything makes sense now! Basically, if $A_r \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times n}$ is invertible $(s^t A_r [I | \hat{A} | G-\hat{A}R_2-R_1]+e^t)[R_1,R_2,I]^t = s^t A_r G + e$, so we first invert to get $s^t A_r$ and use the fact that $A_r$ is invertible to find $s$. Thank you so much, everything is clear now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick aside, while Hermite refers to the same person, "Hermitian" means something different for matrices than "Hermite Normal Form". HNF is essentially "Row Echelon Form/Gaussian Elimination where you can't divide".

---

**HNF Optimization**:

First, we can discuss "Reducing the columns of $E$ modulo the HNF", which does not mean running LLL reduction or something. [MR2009] implicitly defines this notation on page 15:

> In [47] it is proposed to select the vector $v$ such that all the coordinates of $(r+v)$ are reduced modulo the corresponding element along the diagonal of the HNF public basis $H$. The vector $(r+v)$ resulting from such a process is denoted $r\mod H$, and it provably makes cryptanalysis hardest because $r\mod H$ can be efficiently computed from any vector of the form $(r+v)$ with $v\in \mathcal{L}(B)$. So, any attack on $r\mod H$ can be easily adapted to work on any vector of the form $r+v$ by first computing $(r+v) \mod H=r\mod H$. Notice that $r\mod H$ can be computed directly from $r$ and $H$ (without explicitly computing $v$) by iteratively subtracting multiples of the columns of $H$ from $r$. Column $h_{i}$ is used to reduce the $i$th element of $r$ modulo $h_{i,i}$.

This is fairly typical for what "reducing mod a lattice means".
Any lattice partitions space into the union of translates a (non-unique) "fundamental domain" by lattice points. Reducing mod a lattice roughly means (for some fundamental domain) shifting a point in space by lattice points (which preserves the relative position in the fundamental domain) until one gets to the fundamental domain associated with 0. If you have a CVP oracle, these fundamental domains are Voronoi cells, but there are efficient algorithms for "worse" fundamental domains (one is described on page 25 of [MR2009] if you are interested).

This is to say that "reducing mod a lattice" shifts by lattice vectors until you are near the origin while maintaining your *relative position* within some tiling of space.
This is best demonstrated by reduction mod $q$, which has a natural interpretation of reducing mod the lattice $q\mathbb{Z}^n$. The fundamental domain here is $[-q/2, q/2)^n$ (which is the Voronoi cell of the cubic lattice $q\mathbb{Z}^n$), and it maps you from some arbitrary point in space $x = q\vec{y} + e$, where $q\vec{y}\in q\mathbb{Z}^n, e \in[-q/2, q/2)^n$ to $e\in [-q/2, q/2)^n$, where the "relative position being preserved" means that the part of $x$ in the fundamental domain ($e$) is not changed.
Note that for an arbitrary point in space $x$, the "$e$ part" is uniquely determined (as the lattice *partitions* the space into translates of the fundamental domain), so preserving the $e$ part is meaningful.

Returning to page 24, start by considering the public key:

$$[\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{S} + \mathbf{E}]$$

The idea behind the HNF optimization is two-fold:

1. Replace $\mathbf{A}$ with a "succinct" description of the lattice that $\mathbf{S}$ is encoded under
2. Reduce $\mathbf{AS} + \mathbf{E}$ mod the lattice to force $\mathbf{AS} + \mathbf{E}$ to be contained in some "smaller" space, while "preserving the $\mathbf{E}$ part"

Both use the HNF in a key way.
Consider the HNF of the basis of the lattice $\Lambda_q(\mathbf{A}^t)$ again. This can be computed by column-reducing a generating set for the lattice $\Lambda_q(\mathbf{A}^t) = \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A}) + q\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is given by $[\mathbf{A}, q\mathbf{I}]$.
Under the "standard assumptions" on $\mathbf{A}$ (which are listed on the bottom of page 23), this yields a basis of the form:

$$\mathbf{H} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{A}' & q\mathbf{I}\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that changing to this basis does not require modifying our public key in some way.
If $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{U}$ is our expression of the HNF $\mathbf{H}$ in terms of the initial basis and a unimodular matrix, then we simplistically have that:

$$[\mathbf{H}\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{H}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{S} + \mathbf{E}]$$

But $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{U}$ both generate the same lattice, so we can freely replace $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{U}$ with $\mathbf{H}$.
I will next write $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{S}$, which is uniformly random iff $\mathbf{S}$ is ($\mathbf{U}$ is invertible).
We therefore have that the public key is of the form:

$$[\mathbf{H}, \mathbf{H}\mathbf{P} + \mathbf{E}]$$

Examine this second part of the equation now:

$$\mathbf{H}\mathbf{P} + \mathbf{E} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{A}' & q\mathbf{I}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{P}''\\\mathbf{P}'\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{E}'' \\ \mathbf{E}'\end{pmatrix}$$

One can do block-matrix multiplication to get the two equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{P}'' + \mathbf{E}'' \\ \mathbf{A}'\mathbf{P}'' + q\mathbf{P}' + \mathbf{E}'\end{pmatrix}$$

The idea here will be to reduce mod the lattice to zero out the "top" part of the last equation.
If you look at the form of $\mathbf{H}$, this can easily be done without knowing $\mathbf{P}''$ or $\mathbf{E}''$ (the relevant section of $\mathbf{H}$ contains an identity matrix, add columns from that until it is zero).

As I mentioned though, this kind of technique changes the particular lattice point that is being encoded.
As $\mathbf{P}'' + \mathbf{E}'' = 0$, when we zero it out we will have that the encoded point $\mathbf{P}'' = -\mathbf{E}''$ now, yielding the equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-\mathbf{E}'' + \mathbf{E}'' \\ -\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{E}'' + q\mathbf{P}' + \mathbf{E}'\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{0} \\ -\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{E}'' + q\mathbf{P}' + \mathbf{E}'\end{pmatrix}$$
Considered $\bmod q$, this lets one write the public key as:

$$\left[\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{A}' & q\mathbf{I}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{0} \\ -\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{E}'' + \mathbf{E}'\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

This is easily compressible to the pair $[\mathbf{A}', -\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{E}'' + \mathbf{E}']$, which is where one gets the efficiency gain.
Also note that if one can break this LWE instance, they can break LWE.
Consider search LWE for simplicity --- breaking it here lets you recover $\mathbf{E}', \mathbf{E}''$, which is the entirety of $\mathbf{E}$ in the initial LWE instance.
From that you can reduce $[\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{AS} + \mathbf{E}]\mapsto [\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{AS}]$, which is trivially breakable.
This technique can also be used to reduce LWE with Uniform errors to LWE with Gaussian errors. I think if one truly wants uniform errors you could re-randomize this by adding $-\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{U}'$ for uniform $\mathbf{U}'$, but have not thought through this much (also Gaussian errors will be "shorter" on average, so up to issues with sampling discrete Gaussians they often lead to slower error growth).

---

**Reusing a Random Matrix**:

You can reuse the random pad.
Reusing it $\ell$ times roughly gives adversaries an $\ell$ times greater advantage by a simple hybrid argument.
So if $\ell$ is polynomially-sized (which is the largest it can be for honest parties to be able to compute on it) everything is fine. Details can be found in section 6.2 of [PW2007](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/279.pdf). This is what is referred to on slide 8 of the linked slides as well by "multiple secrets" (if you collect the multiple secrets into a matrix, it is precisely your situation).
Note that one of course must reuse $\mathbf{A}$ with independent keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thank you very much for the [PW07] reference: Lemma 6.2 is exactly that. It is very helpful and answers perfectly my question! Concerning the first question, I did try to read the relevant section of [MR09] (the important part is at the very end and a bit in the beginning). However, it still looks a bit cryptic to me, I put more details in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit (sorry for the time I spent to answer, I wanted to make sure I understood everything). You answer is very complementary from Peikert's comments, and helped me a lot in understanding everything. Thanks again!